# Run a function on matched URL in Angular NGXS

Tags: angular, ngxs, angular-state-managmement

Is there a way to run a function when matched a specific URL.
For example:
If i matched a URL "/home". Would it possible to run this action

> this.store.dispatch(new SampleAction())

Comment: When your url is matched then lets say your "HomeComponent" is loaded. Simply run this on ngOnInit() of your HomeComponent

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm. That's what i did. but what if you have many url to match. Would you run this on every ngOnInit() on every component? Is there a way on just a single file to do this?

Comment: So what's the problem to subscribe to the `router.events`, filter by some event `NavigationEnd` or `NavigationStart` (I don't know what do you need), then filter by the needed url and `switchMap` to the `store.dispatch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.- For a single Route:**

You could just execute your function in the `onInit()`-function of your Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
//your code here
  }

}
```

As soon as your navigating to the route, your function will be executed.
Note that your route should be added to your routing-moudle:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'youRoute', component: YourComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

**2.- Same Function multiple Routes**

If you want to execute the same code for multiple routes you could listen to route changes. Your router outlet should look like this:

```
<router-outlet (activate)="routeChange()"></router-outlet>
```

And in your component:

```
  constructor(public route: Router) {}    

  myRoutes: string[] = ['/tools', '/home'];

  routeChange() {
    if (this.myRoutes.some(e => e === this.route.url)) {
      console.log('execute');
    } else {
      console.log('dont execute');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just put the dispatch in the constructor of the HomeComponent?

Otherwise you could use a guard for this:

Route:

```
  path: '/home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [DispatchGuard]
```

Guard

```
@Injectable()
export class DispatchGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor() { }

  canActivate(): boolean {
    this.store.dispatch(new SampleAction())
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here would work however another option is available if you are using the NGXS [Router Plugin](https://www.ngxs.io/plugins/router#usage). You could listen to the stream for router actions e.g. `RouterNavigation`, then if the route matches what you are looking for, dispatch the action.

```
constructor(private actions$: Actions, private store: Store) {

// Listen to the NGXS action stream for when the router navigation changes
this.actions$
    .pipe(ofActionDispatched(RouterNavigation))
    .subscribe(({routerState}: RouterNavigation) => {

      // If routerState matches your conditions then dispatch the action
        if (routerState == ) { 
          this.store.dispatch(new SampleAction());
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: Will i put this in a separate file and how would this run? Do i need to put in the providers?

Comment: Depending on how you want it to work, you could hook it into your main `app.component` or load it when the app starts up via `APP_INITIALIZER`

Comment: Yes i want it to load on start of the app. Can you edit your code? Thanks

Comment: On startup you need to load it as a provider in your main `App.Module` - see the examples [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#predefined-tokens-and-multiple-providers)

Comment: Thanks I tried providing it but it still not functioning. It doesn't appear in console when i tried console.log